# Segmentation Fault(core dumped) while writing to a file

Tags: c++, filestream

I have written this code to create planar graphs of the tree format in which each node will have random no of childs and all level nodes will be connected and all leaf nodes will be connected in a loop. The graphs generating are fine but while trying to write them in a text file, it causing "segmentation fault(code dumped)", it's happening only when i enter to generated graphs greater than 5 or 6. I think this is happening because of the memory boundations but i tried clearing all the queues, and already all the queues are emptied before writing the graph to the file.

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<queue>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void updateGraph(int x,int n,int s);
void printGraph(bool **gh,int len);
void clearQueue(queue<int> &q );

bool **g = NULL;
int vertexCount = 0;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Tree- Planar Graph generation"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the no of graphs to be generated"<<endl;
    int no_graphs = 0;
    cin>>no_graphs;
    int verticesNo = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    ofstream my_file("planar_tree_graphs.txt",ios :: out);

    if(my_file.is_open())
    {
        my_file << no_graphs;
        my_file << "\n";
        for(int k=0;k<no_graphs;k++)
        {
            g = NULL;
            verticesNo = 5;
            vertexCount = 0;

            //verticesNo = rand() % 21;
            //verticesNo = verticesNo + 50;

            my_file << verticesNo;
            my_file << "\n";

            int v = 0;
            queue<int> leaf;
            queue<int> level;
            queue<int> levelv;
            //cout<<level.empty();
            //cout<<levelv.empty();
            level.push(0);
            level.push(-1);
            v++;

            vertexCount = 1;
            g = new bool*[1];
            g[0] = new bool[1];
            g[0][0] = false;

            while(v < verticesNo && !level.empty())
            {
                if(level.front() == -1)
                {   //cout<<"levelv "<<levelv.empty()<<endl;
                    while(!levelv.empty())
                    {
                        int x = levelv.front();
                        if(x == -1)
                        {
                            levelv.pop();
                            //cout<<"x-break"<<endl;
                            break;
                        }
                        levelv.pop();
                        int y = levelv.front();
                        if(y == -1)
                        {
                            levelv.pop();
                            //cout<<"y-break"<<endl;
                            break;
                        }
                        //cout<<"left"<<endl;
                        g[x][y] = true;
                        g[y][x] = true;
                    }
                    //cout<<"poped"<<endl;
                    //cout<<"levelv "<<levelv.empty()<<endl;
                    level.pop();
                    //cout<<"level "<<level.empty()<<endl;
                }

                int vertex = level.front();
                level.pop();
                while(vertex == -1 && !level.empty())
                {
                    vertex = level.front();
                    level.pop();
                }
                if(vertex == -1)
                    break;

                int nadj = 0;
                if(v + 10 >= verticesNo)
                    nadj = rand() % (verticesNo - v + 1);
                else
                    nadj = rand() % 10;

                while(v == 1 && nadj == 0)
                {
                    if(v + 10 >= verticesNo)
                        nadj = rand() % (verticesNo - v + 1);
                    else
                        nadj = rand() % 10;
                }
                //cout<<"goit"<<endl;
                if(nadj == 0)
                {
                    leaf.push(vertex);
                    //cout<<"vertex "<<vertex<<endl;
                }

                for(int i=v;i<v+nadj;i++)
                {
                    level.push(i);
                    levelv.push(i);
                }
                if(level.front() == -1)
                {
                    levelv.push(-1);
                    level.push(-1);
                }
                updateGraph(vertex,nadj,v);
                //printGraph(g,vertexCount);
                v = v + nadj;
            }
            //cout<<"over"<<endl;
            while(!levelv.empty())
            {
                int x = levelv.front();
                levelv.pop();
                while(x == -1)
                {
                    x = levelv.front();
                    levelv.pop();
                }

                if(levelv.empty())
                    break;

                int y = levelv.front();
                while(y == -1)
                {
                    levelv.pop();
                    y = levelv.front();
                }
                //cout<<"x "<<x<<" y "<<y<<endl;
                g[x][y] = true;
                g[y][x] = true;
            }

            //cout<<"over2"<<endl;
            //for cycle
            while(!level.empty())
            {
                int x = level.front();
                level.pop();
                while(x == -1 && !level.empty())
                {
                    x = level.front();
                    level.pop();
                }
                if(x != -1)
                {
                    leaf.push(x);
                    //cout<<"x "<<x<<endl;
                }
            }
            //cout<<"over3"<<endl;
            if(leaf.size() >= 2)
            {
                //cout<<"inside"<<endl;
                int x = leaf.front();
                int y = leaf.back();
                //cout<<x<<y<<endl;
                g[x][y] = true;
                g[y][x] = true;
            }

            //cout<<"over4"<<endl;
            while(!leaf.empty())
            {
                int x = leaf.front();
                leaf.pop();

                if(leaf.empty())
                    break;

                int y = leaf.front();
                leaf.pop();

                if(leaf.empty())
                    break;

                //cout<<"x "<<x<<" y "<<y<<endl;
                g[x][y] = true;
                g[y][x] = true;
            }
            cout<<leaf.empty();
            cout<<level.empty();
            cout<<levelv.empty();
            for(int m = 0;m<verticesNo;m++)
            {
                for(int n = 0;n<verticesNo;n++)
                {
                    my_file << g[m][n];
                    my_file << "\t";
                }
                my_file << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    my_file.close();

    cout<<no_graphs<<" generated successfully!"<<endl;
    cout<<"All graphs are stored in a file named- planar_tree_graphs.txt"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void updateGraph(int x,int n,int s)
{
    bool **dummy = NULL;
    dummy = new bool*[vertexCount];
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        dummy[i] = new bool[vertexCount];

    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
            dummy[i][j] = g[i][j];

    //cout<<"dummy"<<endl;
    //printGraph(dummy,vertexCount);

    g = NULL;
    vertexCount = vertexCount + n;
    g = new bool*[vertexCount];
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        g[i] = new bool[vertexCount];

    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
            g[i][j] = false;

    //cout<<"new initial"<<endl;
    //printGraph(g,vertexCount);

    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount-n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<vertexCount-n;j++)
            g[i][j] = dummy[i][j];

    //cout<<"dummy copy"<<endl;
    //printGraph(g,vertexCount);

    for(int i=s;i<vertexCount;i++)
    {
        g[x][i] = true;
        g[i][x] = true;
    }
}

void printGraph(bool **gh,int vertexCount)
{
    cout<<"Graph is: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
            cout<<gh[i][j]<<" ";

        cout<<"\n";
    }
}

void clearQueue(queue<int> &q )
{
   queue<int> empty;
   swap( q, empty );
}
```

Comment: Instead of `bool**`, why didn't you use `std::vector<std::vector<bool>>`?  Then all of that memory management you're doing would go away.  In addition, you could utilize `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` to detect out-of-bounds accesses in `g`.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** `gdb` & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: As PaulMcKenzie get rid of the dynamic memory stuff. Now it seems to leak memory as you never call delete. If you can't use a debugger for some reason then add `cout << "Step .... " << endl;" a number of places to find where the seg fault happens.

Comment: @OP.  I will do you a favor.  Take this code:  http://ideone.com/vWvV3l  It is the equivalent to your code (please check it), but uses `vector` and `at()`.  Build and run it.  Do you see an `out_of_range` exception?  If it does throw an exception, then you will know which line caused it.  Start debugging.  Once you remove all of those errors, then replace `at()` with `[ ]`.

Comment: Thanks all, Yup Paul, it was throwing an out_of_range exception, thanks a lot, i was just debugging it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie vector<bool> has some issues, even vector<int8_t> would be better

Comment: @M.M Yes, I know that it has issues.  However the OP's current code wasn't using it in a way where the issues would arise.